# Long display name with no spaces breaks design of review history pages

Tags: bug, review, design, meta

See for yourself:

> [image: broken design of suggested edits history]

Name with a space doesn't cause any problem as far as I could see.

Comment: Where is it supposed to break?

Comment: @Scimonster dunno exactly, but same way it's limited in posts e.g. [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QxuHn.png) it should be limited in other places so it won't break the design.

Answer (score 2):

While waiting for a proper fix, I've added a CSS fix for this bug into the development branch of the [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script.  Here's the added CSS:

```css
body.review-page .history-table td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 120px;
    max-width: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: #999;
}
```

and here's a screenshot of the result:

> [image: screenshot]

Assuming no unexpected side effects turn up, this fix should be part of the next stable SOUP release (v1.34).  In the mean time, folks who like to live on the edge may [install the development version of SOUP](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/devel/SOUP.user.js) with all the [latest fixes](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/devel/CHANGELOG.md) (and, occasionally, all the latest bugs too).