# Excessively long edit summary breaks Revision History page

Tags: bug, revisions-list

**[Affected page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/82303/revisions)**

**Screenshot:** (right click -> open image in new tab)

[image]

**Edit summary text:**

```
corrected citation; the prev citation was neither in indian edition neither in the archived edition (https://ia801304.us.archive.org/15/items/ConciseInorganicChemistry4thEditionByJ.D.Lee/Concise%20Inorganic%20Chemistry%20%284th%20Edition%29%20by%20J.D.Lee.pdf) if you find any inconsistency ping me
```

**Self-observation:**  Apparently any lengthy no-space string (like the URL) breaks the `.revision .revision-comment` on the `https://site.stackexchange.com/posts/xyz/revisions` page.

Comment: [Related but not exact duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242944/long-display-name-with-no-spaces-breaks-design-of-review-history-pages)

Comment: [Click here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/307519/revisions)

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ Whoa that page is really bugggy!